# AngularJS execute scope function after ngClass changed

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have the following setup in my `AngularJS` project:

### Controller

```
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $timeout, someService) {

    $scope.showItem = false;

    $scope.show = function() {
        $scope.showItem = true;
        $scope.showCharts();
    };

    $scope.showCharts = function() {
        // this code needs the HTML elements to have a width and height
        console.log($('#chartContainer').width()); // prints always 0
    };
}
```

### View

```
<div id="details" ng-class="{visible: showItem}">
    <div id="chartContainer"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#details {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease .25s;
}

#details.visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

A specific part of the website is only shown when the controller method is invoked, otherwise it has `opacity: 0`. The controller sets the `boolean` property to true (which will trigger the element to appear). However, in the `$scope.showCharts();` method, the `element's width` is always `0`. The only thing that works for me is using a timeout:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.showCharts(); // the width will be set now
}, 150);
```

This is, of course, a terrible solution. Does anyone know how I can call a scope function once the class has changed and the `DOM` is ready?

Comment: why do you think that $timeout is terrible soulutiion, while you use transition via css?

Comment: $timeout for this situation is the best, eventually you can observe the transitionend event on #details but i think is a waste

Comment: @paka I don't like it because the code that should be executed (`$scope.showCharts()`) isn't linked to what really is going on in the website. If someone changes the `CSS` transition durations, the controller timeout won't work anymore. This seems rather unclean to me. In other words, some link exists between CSS styling and the JS code that is really easy to miss. Maybe I try with the `transitionend` event. Thanks for the input so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `$watch` on the width of the chart and do whatever you need to do at the time it changes.  For example something like this.

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() {
        return jQuery("#chartContainer").width();
    },
    function() {
        // Do what you want when the size changes
    }
);
```